# CSS: Sorry, the at-rule @keyframes is not implemented

Tags: css

Trying to make a simple animation using example found at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_keyframes2 as a reference

however, the image which i'm trying to animate stands still. Aptana editor spits out these errors -"Property animation doesn't exist, "Property animation-iteration-count doesn't exist", "Sorry, the at-rule @keyframes is not implemented".

my html:

```
<div id="animate"><img src="flower.jpg"> </div>
```

my css:

```
#animate img 
{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    animation: test 25s;
    animation-iteration-count: 10;
    -moz-animation: test 25s;
}

@keyframes test
{
0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
25%  {left:200px; top:0px;}
50%  {left:200px; top:200px;}
75%  {left:0px; top:200px;}
100% {left:0px; top:0px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes test
{
0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
25%  {left:200px; top:0px;}
50%  {left:200px; top:200px;}
75%  {left:0px; top:200px;}
100% {left:0px; top:0px;}
}
```

The third error, "Sorry, the at-rule @keyframes is not implemented" - does it mean that this feature is not officially implemented worldwide? if so, why the example code at W3schools works OK, but the code from my editor does not work?

using Mozilla 18.0.2 on windows

Comment: Aptana is weird like that. You should just test in the browser directly.

Comment: Aptana has its own definitions of what it expects in HTML/CSS. These are often our of date as the standard moves forward faster than the application updates do. Ignore the editor, use a real browser.

Comment: ok. but i still cannot animate image. anything wrong with the code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for me. I added a containing class just to be sure.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JBdgk

Also, you've only written moz keyframes. You are testing this in Firefox, right?

Comment: great, it began to work as soon as i added `position: relative` to #animate img selector!
didn't consider `position: relative` to be important in making element move ;)

Comment: That allows your absolute positioning to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

Wc3 validator sees @-webkit-keyframes as not implemended because it is vendor specific. So it's not your problem, or the editor's problem, it's wc3 validation standards.